# Riemann integral and (un)equal partitions

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

In the original definition of the Riemann integral we use partitions of the interval in which the sub-intervals do not need to be of equal length. Is there any example in which the sub-intervals of equal length will cause some problems (proofs, computations)? With many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the partitions get smaller and smaller any partitioning will do and they will converge to the same limit if it exists. Sometimes by choosing a clever partition you can make an otherwise difficult integral very easy if say, the function is always zero at the partition points.

You may be interested in [conditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) sequences which can be made to take on any value by rearranging the order of the terms as proven by the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem). They will give you some idea of how complications can arise if we treat infinite series carelessly.

Comment: Fully agree. Anyway, it would be interesting to have a particular example for the Riemann integral. Out or curiosity.

Comment: Wait are you saying not only equal length subintervals are good enough but any sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ is good enough as long as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} ||P_n||=0$? I'll see if I can come up with a proof of this. If this already a well known result, can you point me to a proof? This seems kind of like way too good to be true.

Comment: @William it is true and and I expect you can prove this. Introduction to Mathematical Analysis by Douglass has a proof if you get stuck.

Comment: Do you have a pdf of Douglass? I couldn't seem to find one by googling :(

Comment: @William no I only have a hardcopy.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Thomae's function on $[0,1]$.
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac1q, \text{ if }x=\frac{p}{q}, \text{ with } p\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and }q\in\mathbb{N} \text{ coprime};\\
0, \text{ if }x\notin \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
The Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$ can be shown by definition, which is that the supremum of lower Riemann sum equals to the infimum of upper Riemann sum.
For any partition $P$ of $[0,1]$, the lower Riemann sum of $f$ at $P$ would be $0$.
The reason is as follows.
Every interval on $\mathbb{R}$ contains irrational and rational numbers. The value of $f$ on rational numbers must be greater than $0$, so the infimum within every interval would be $0$, which is the value of $f$ at every irrational point.
So, the supremum of lower Riemann sum is $0$.

Showing that the infimum of upper Riemann sum is more complicating, but I am sure that you can find some resource at other question.

Now, the Riemann integral of Thomae function on $[0,1]$ at equal-length partitions is $0$, the value of definite Riemann integral $\int_0^1f(x)dx$. That is,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\frac{i}{n})\cdot\frac1n=\int_0^1f(x)dx=0
$$

Keep this in mind, because we are going to change the Thomae function.

We select a real number $a\neq0$. This would be the value of new function on irrational numbers. See the following definition.
Define $\hat{f}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
\hat{f}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac1q, \text{ if }x=\frac{p}{q}, \text{ with } p\in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and }q\in\mathbb{N} \text{ coprime};\\
a, \text{ if }x\notin \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
One can show that $\hat{f}$ is discontinuous at every point. By Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, the set of discontinuous points has measure more than $0$, so $\hat{f}$ is not Riemann integrable.

However, we can still compute this:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\hat{f}(\frac{i}{n})\cdot\frac1n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(\frac{i}{n})\cdot\frac1n=0
$$
as $f$ and $\hat{f}$ have the same value on rational numbers.

In this example, we see that even if the Riemann integral of $\hat{f}$ on $[0,1]$ at equal-length partitions exists, this function is not Riemann integrable. I thought that this is the "problem" you were looking for.